# How do I get a public object[] variable to appear in Unitys inspector

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, serialization

I would like to make an array of objects appear in Unity's inspector. Then I can assign various things to it as arguments when a user presses a button.

This would mean having the convenience of being able to assign arguments to it within the Unity Editor.

```
public string event;
public object[] args;
```

Then when the user presses a button

```
public void OnPointerDown(PointerEventData eventData)
{
    app.Notify(event+ "@down", this, args);
}
```

Some class then recieves the notification

```
 public override void OnNotification(string p_event, Object p_target, params object[] p_args)
    {
        // Do something with p_event and p_args[0] 
    }
```

But I am unable to get object[] args to display in the inspector

Comment: Try adding the `[SerializeField]` attribute above the variable.

Comment: IMO I'm not quite sure if you can. I would try to make a wrapper for your parameters like `class Parameter { public readonly object Param; public Parameter(object param) { Param = param; } }` and then use it in your array `public Parameter[] args;` and then derive from it with diferent types. Problem is that `object` is way too broad definition, you could add integer, string, char ... basically anything to this field so inspector will have a hard time trying to give you adequate visual edit control.